# Wordpress do_action password_reset is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using wordpress 4.7.3. Password reset is not working. When i debugged my code. I reached to this line inside users.php reset_password():

```
do_action( 'password_reset', $user, $new_pass );
```

Soon after there is a line :

```
wp_set_password( $new_pass, $user->ID );
```

Because do_action is not working, its not going inside the wp_set_password function. I don't why default wordpress reset password is not working. Stucked from last 2 days. Expert suggestion please?

Comment: How to you know that it doesn't work? have you debug it? did you check what callbacks set to `password_reset`. Toomuch questiosn without answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!is_user_logged_in())   
  {
     $new_pass='password';
     $user='1';
     wp_set_password( $new_pass, $user);  
  }
```

please try this